# memory leak using AsyncTask as a inner class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-memory

Im using an AsyncTask called GetSalesTask as an inner class in my Activity, but it seems that it is leaking, I can see a lot of instances alive from the same GetSalesTask class, in other words it seems that the instances of GetSalesTask are alive and are not cleaned from memory.
Can you please point out where can my problem be?

```
 class LeekClass extends BaseProfileActivity{ 
    void callTask()
    {
        new GetSaleTask().execute();
    }
    private class GetSalesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                showList(true);
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    List<Sale> saleList = get Data From Database
                    mItems.clear();
                    mItems.addAll(saleList);
                    if (saleList.size() > 0)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                BaseProfileActivity baseAct = (BaseProfileActivity) getActivity();
                if (baseAct != null && getView() != null && mAdapter != null) {
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    showList(true);
                    baseAct.getProgress().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The methods showList(true); getView(); and the variables mItems,mAdapter are defined in the activity.

Comment: You should take a look at http://simonvt.net/2014/04/17/asynctask-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/ . You are keeping a reference to your Activity meaning it won't get GC'ed until your Activity is.

Answer (score 1):

Consider setting the task to null in onPostExecute and checking for null before starting the task.  The GC should in theory trace back to the null and determine everything is ok to clean up.

```
if (myTask==null) {
    myTask = new getSaleTask();  
    myTask.execute(); 
}
```

somewhere in `onPostExecute();`

```
myTask =null;
```

I've switched to doing the above and passing `WeakReference<T>` Pass a WeakReference to the class.  This is easier for me to do in a constructor.  Below I pass a `WeakReference<Context>` to the class.  Save the weakReference in the constructor of the class.

```
new getSaleTask(new WeakReference<Context>(getApplicationContext());

public getSaleTask(WeakReference<Context> weakReference){
    this.weakReference = weakReference;
}
```

then in the class you get the WeakReference as follows.

```
Context context = weakReference.get();
```

For whatever reason set the weakReference to null when the task is finished.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I put a solution like you suggested, I'm checking if the task is already running before i start it. About the week references to be honest it is the first time i meet them and it seams that they could be usefully. Any interesting post on WeakReferences ? Thanks

Comment: The only thing I saw on weakReference was at developer.android.com?